# Git command inside hook fails

Tags: git

The following command runs successfully when run from the git bash with my desired results.

```
git rev-list --no-merges --pretty=oneline $new_ref --not $old_ref refs/heads/built
```

When I run the same command inside a git update hook, it fails with this error.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/built': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate filenames from revisions
```

If I add the `--`, I don't get the same results as when I run it from the git bash outside of the hook.

Seems to have problems with the forward slashes.  I've tried escaping them etc...

Any ideas, Thanks!

Comment: Try `git rev-list --no-merges --pretty=oneline $new_ref --not $old_ref built`.  Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I added a sed command to strip all the refs/heads/ from the git command.